# Left outer join and get the three columns from three tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Below is my SQL query

```sql
SELECT  ( ( ( ( ( ( 'L' + ( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t0.Length) ) ) + 'W' ) + ( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t0.Width) ) ) +
              'H' ) + ( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t0.Height) ) ) + ' - ' ) + t0.DimUoM AS 'Dimensions'
      , ( ( ( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t0.NetWt) ) + '  (' ) + t0.NetWtUoM ) + ')' AS 'Weight'
      , t0.UPCCode
      , t1.DisplayBrand AS 'Brand'
      , t2.ID
FROM    SmartSearchNewQA.dbo.MaterialMaster AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BrandConversion AS t1
        ON t0.Brand = t1.SAPBrand
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClickCommerce.dbo.tblWarrantyPartReturn AS t2
        ON t0.MaterialNumber = t2.PartNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClickCommerce.dbo.tblWarrantyPartReturnAddress AS t3
        ON t2.ReturnCode = t3.ReturnCode
WHERE   t0.MaterialNumber = 'S1-326000' AND
        t2.DistributorId = '00100';
```

[image: Query Result]

AM trying to convert the above query to LINQ and not able to map the second table . Please find the below LINQ i derived so far

```
from mm in ctx.MaterialMasters
join bc in ctx.BrandConversions on mm.Brand equals bc.SAPBrand into bc1
from brandConv in bc1.DefaultIfEmpty()  
join wp1 in ctx.tblWarrantyPartReturns  
  on mm.MaterialNumber equals wp1.PartNumber into bc2
from  partconv in bc2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join wp2 in ctx.tblWarrantyPartReturnAddresses 
  on bc2
from partconv2 in bc3.DefaultIfEmpty()
where mm.MaterialNumber == materialNumber
select new MaterialHeader 
{
    Brand = brandConv.DisplayBrand,
    Dimensions = "L" + mm.Length + ":W" + mm.Width + ":H" + mm.Height + " - " + mm.DimUoM,
    UPCCode = mm.UPCCode,
    Weight = mm.NetWt + " (" + mm.NetWtUoM + ")"
})
```

Kindly help me to arrive the above SQL result with the LINQ query.

Thanks

Comment: Ouch that query is horrible to read. All those [ and ] plus absolutely useless aliases makes this user hostile at best. Then there are the crazy amount of redundant ( and ). I know you trying to move this to LINQ but you should read more about why those aliases are bad. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, and it wouldn't format decently anyway. Here is what that same query would look using meaningful aliases. I also removed all the redunant parenthesis and square brackets. This is much easier to see what i going on.

```
SELECT 'L' + CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX), mm.Length) + 'W' + CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX), mm.Width) + 'H' + CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX), mm.Height) + ' - ' + mm.DimUoM AS Dimensions
    , CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX), mm.NetWt) + '  (' + mm.NetWtUoM + ')' AS Weight
    , mm.UPCCode
    , bc.DisplayBrand AS Brand
    , wpr.ID
FROM SmartSearchNewQA.dbo.MaterialMaster AS mm
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.BrandConversion AS bc ON mm.Brand = bc.SAPBrand
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ClickCommerce.dbo.tblWarrantyPartReturn  as wpr on mm.MaterialNumber  = wpr.PartNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN  ClickCommerce.dbo.tblWarrantyPartReturnAddress  as wpra on  wpr.ReturnCode = wpra.ReturnCode
WHERE mm.MaterialNumber = 'S1-326000' 
    AND wpr.DistributorId ='00100'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
from t0 in ctx.MaterialMasters
join t1 in ctx.BrandConversions
    on t0.Brand equals t1.SAPBrand into firstLeftJoin
from m in firstLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t2 in ctx2.tblWarrantyPartReturns
    on t2.PartNumber equals m.MaterialNumber into secondLeftJoin
from n in secondLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join t3 in ctx2.tblWarrantyPartReturnAddress
    on t3.ReturnCode equals n.ReturnCode into thirdLeftJoin
from s in thirdLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t0.MaterialNumber = "S1-326000" &&
    t2.DistributorId = "00100"
select new MaterialHeader {
                            Brand = t1.DisplayBrand,
                            Dimensions = "L" + t0.Length + ":W" + t0.Width + ":H" + t0.Height + " - " + t0.DimUoM,
                            UPCCode = t0.UPCCode,
                            Weight = t0.NetWt + " (" + t0.NetWtUoM + ")"
                          }
```

It captured my attention that you have two databases: SmartSearchNewQA and ClickCommerce. In your SQL query, so I used two database contexts: ctx and ctx2. Assuming you will have each database separated.

You can also try [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net) to develop LINQ skills.